# Did I write this constructor properly?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, singly-linked-list

I am working on a project for my Data Structures class that asks me to write a class to implement a linked list of ints. Use an inner class for the Node. Include the methods below. Write a tester to enable you to test all of the methods with whatever data you want in any order. I have to create three different constructors. One of the constructors is meant to be a constructor that takes an array of ints and creates a linked list containing all of the ints. I've tried doing the code below. But I'm not sure I wrote the code correctly? Can someone verify I wrote the code correctly or let me know what I need to change so the code is written correctly?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class LinkedListOfIntsTest {
    Node head;
    int[] array;
    Node other;

    private class Node {
        int value;
        Node nextNode;

        public Node(int value, Node nextNode) {
            this.value = value;
            this.nextNode = nextNode;
        }

    }

    public LinkedListOfIntsTest() {
        
    }

    public LinkedListOfIntsTest(int[] other) {
        array = new int[other.length];
        
    }
```

Comment: You would not have an array of int in the class since it's suppose to be a linked list of ints. The ints themselves are stored in the `value` field of `Node.

Comment: No, this isn't correct.  The default constructor leaves you with three references all initialized to null.  I wouldn't consider that correct.  The Node references are both null in the other constructor.  Shouldn't your LinkedList be a generic class?  Is this a LinkedList implementation or a test class?  Confusing names.  If it's a LinkedList, what is the array of ints for?  Makes no sense.  I'd start with an interface.  What methods are common to all LinkedLists?

Comment: What would I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the whole idea is to convert the array into a `LinkedList`, rather than just storing the array.  So you should remove `Node other` and `int[] array` from the fields of the class.

One way to do the conversion would be to convert each element of the array into a `Node`, linking in the previous one as you go, like this.

```
public LinkedListOfIntsTest(int[] other) {
    Node[] nodes = new Node[other.length];
    for( int index = 0; index < other.length; index++ ) {
        nodes[index] = new Node(other[index], null);
        if (index > 0) {
            nodes[index - 1].nextNode = nodes[index];
        }
    }
    
    head = nodes[0];
}
```

Here, `nodes` is just a local variable, because you don't need it any more after the constructor has finished.

Comment: Ok, the only reason I had Node other was because of another constructor I have which is a copy constructor "public LinkedListOfIntsTest(LinkedListOfIntsTest other)". Inside the constructor, I wrote "this.other = head;" Which I'm not sure was the correct way of doing it.