# Did I write the copy constructor for my Linked List program correctly?

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, copy-constructor

I am working on a project for my Data Structures class that asks me to write a class to implement a linked list of ints.

> - Use an inner class for the Node.
> - Include the methods below.
> - Write a tester to enable you to test all of the methods with whatever data you want in any order.

I have to create three different constructors. One of the constructors is a copy constructor. I have my code down below showing what I did but I'm not sure I wrote this constructor correctly. I also have a method called addToFront one of the many methods I need to implement in this project. Can someone let me know what I would need to write for the copy constructor? I have no idea what I need to write for a copy constructor. I've tried looking it up but the examples shown don't match with what I'm trying to write.

```
public class LinkedListOfInts {
    Node head;

    private class Node {
        int value;
        Node nextNode;

        public Node(int value, Node nextNode) {
            this.value = value;
            this.nextNode = nextNode;
        }

    }
    
    public LinkedListOfInts() {
        
    }
    
    public LinkedListOfInts(LinkedListOfInts other) {
        
    }

    public void addToFront(int x) {
        head = new Node(x, head);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = " ";
        for (Node ptr = head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.nextNode)
            result += ptr.value + " ";
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListOfInts list = new LinkedListOfInts();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            list.addToFront(i);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why does the constructor with the LinkedListOfIntsTest parameter written is such a way, isn't suppose to be passing in a Head Node and a list of all other nodes?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-a-linked-list-in-java-using-class/ Maybe this could help in your class and for your own understanding

Comment: That’s how my professor had it set up in class. He wanted the class to copy it and we worked on some methods but now he wants us to add on to this and have a bunch of methods implemented along with some constructors.

Comment: So `LinkedListOfIntsTest` is a node? If that is the case, that the inner class node doesn't seem to be needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69592057/2970947

Comment: LinkedListOfIntsTest is the name of the class. I have an empty constructor by that name but I also need a copy constructor that takes in LinkedListOfInts Object. The problem is I don’t know how to do that. I did what I thought was the correct way but I’m not sure.

Comment: No.  This is not right.  Please re-read the "hint" that gave you in a previous question (which you appear to have deleted.)

Comment: The only thing I can think of for this copy constructor is writing this.other = other.head. If this is not the case then I don’t know what to do. I just started learning about Linked List last Monday. This is all new to me so I’m not sure what the copy constructor should look like based on my code.

Comment: At present your `public LinkedListOfIntsTest(LinkedListOfIntsTest other)` constructor completely ignores the parameter you are passing.

Comment: *"The only thing I can think of for this copy constructor ... "*  -  As I said previously.   This constructor needs to do the following:  1) initialize this list as an empty list.  2) iterate the `other` list, getting each value and adding it to this list.  You need to write the `add` method (or whatever you are going to call it) first.

Comment: The "magic trick" to programming that beginners seem to miss is that you need to understand the task that you are trying to perform before you start writing code.  Then you make the code do the task according to your understanding.

Comment: I added a method called addToFront. One of the many methods I need to implement in this project. Hopefully know you know how to help me because I'm lost on this and I still have no idea what the point of a copy constructor is. All I know is my professor wants this to be included in the project and I need to have it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the nodes of the other list and sequentially create new tail nodes based on their values.

```
public LinkedListOfInts(LinkedListOfInts other) {
    Node tail = null;
    for(Node n = other.head; n != null; n = n.nextNode){
        if(tail == null) this.head = tail = new Node(n.value, null);
        else {
            tail.nextNode = new Node(n.value, null);
            tail = tail.nextNode;
        }
    }
}
// ...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedListOfInts list = new LinkedListOfInts();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        list.addToFront(i);
    LinkedListOfInts copy = new LinkedListOfInts(list);
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(copy);
}
```